# programmatically get UDID for a demo app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, udid

There are two parts to this question;

First, is there a way to get user's UDID and automatically add it to certified device list?

Second, can Ad hoc be used as a demo app (Documents mentioned testers and other developers but not potentials customers/employers)?

Comment: Testflight may be a simpler approach; it removes the need to obtain UDIDs

Comment: we have a demo site where we would like to put the demo app, so testflight is out of question for us. we thought it would be a pain, whenever give our link to someone, he/she needs give us their udid. most of them may not be developer or testers, so there will be many questions. http://get.udid.io/ allows us to get customers/employers' udid thru email, but that'll take awhile and it may happens at odd hour we won't be able to get back in time. Sorry for this long explanation, by the way thanks for your reply.

Comment: The problem with obtaining UDIDs is that you then need to add the UDID to your provisioning profile, re-sign the app and update the app image on your web site.  If you use Testflight then all you need is their email address and you can add them to your testflight list; you still can't do it directly.  You can try https://www.diawi.com/ but I have never used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my answer helps you I would be happy!

**Answer 1 :**

**UDID Finding Process**

1. Open the following link in your iOS device : http://get.udid.io/
2. Click on `Tap to find your UDID`
3. It will lead you to Install Profile where you can find INSTALL in top right corner. Tap on it
4. Now you will be redirected to a webpage which will show you the `UDID`. Share that ID to developer team.

**Answer 2 :**

1. Archive your project to create `.ipa` file.
2. Upload your `.ipa` file to this link http://diawi.com/ to create app link.
3. Provide the link to your testing team.

*Note:* This link is not permanent and will expire within a month.

Comment: Please read their 'How it works' they quoted as 'UDID.io provides all information to you and doesn't get access to anything of this'. Also Vice-President of Sandboxx Mr.Andrew appreciated their work, FYI Sandboxx is a company dealing with military social network. I think they are much care about the security than us.